# How can I generate random number $x$ and $y$ from a copula function by using lambert function

Tags: r, machine-learning, distributions, copula, vine-copula

I studied a research paper they are using the lambert function to generate random number x and y from a Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern (FGM) copula function in the simulation study, I tried to understand how the author used the Lambert function so I can write a program in R software but I didn't get too much.
I am wondering if we can use the Lambert function for any copula function in the simulation study.
(paper link https://s3arch.page/results.php?q=Morgenstern%20type%20bivariate%20Lindley%20distribution%20V.S.%20Vaidyanathan%E2%88%97,%20Sharon%20Varghese.%20A
[image: steps of simulation]

I am so grateful for any assistance thanks.

Comment: What is the paper and lambert function and what does FGM stand for

Comment: @develarist Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern

Comment: @develarist u can download the paper from the link                         
https://s3arch.page/results.php?q=Morgenstern%20type%20bivariate%20Lindley%20distribution%20V.S.%20Vaidyanathan%E2%88%97,%20Sharon%20Varghese.%20A

Comment: Or rather, edit the relevant information into your question and include a reference to the paper. Don't just link to necessary information - your question should be able to stand alone. If a link disappears it shouldn't impact the question

Comment: This question appears to have only the trivial answer "because that's the marginal quantile function the authors chose."  There doesn't appear to be any information in the question about why they chose it.  This is probably hidden behind the mysterious "MTBLD" in the quotation.